# Visiblox LabelsContainer adjust?

Tags: c#, wpf, visiblox

Is it possible to adjust Visiblox's labels container? I have encounter a problem with render ranges of axis. Image:

[image: Labaled axis]

As You can see there is a problem with width of each label (there is 75, and then 10 (one zero has gone)), and my code for ranges is:

```
 <charts:LinearAxis.Range>
     <charts:DoubleRange Minimum="-150" Maximum="150"/>
 </charts:LinearAxis.Range>
```

But! If I changed it ranges to -1500,1500 i get this:

[image: -1500 to 1500 ranges]

And in this case, label for value 750 display as 75.

Have I change style or tamplate to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it after playing around with properties of main window, and... simply can't do:

`UseLayoutRounding="True"`

After setting it on False, I got this:

[image: visiblox good]

I hope, that this will be useful for someone :)

PS.: That "bug" was in WPF (I have forgot to write about it)